# Haskell parse time duration from string into DiffTime

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to parse and do operations on timestamps such as this one:

```
"01:46:22,041"
```

which stands for: 1 hour, 46 minutes, 22 seconds and 41 milliseconds.

I don't really know where to begin here. The existing datatypes all seem to include a date.
In my case, I only need to add/substract from the timestamp and then print it out in the same format.

I obviously don't want to write my own calculator if there's one built in. Is there any standard way to tackle this in Haskell?

Answer (score 7):

Use [Data.Time.Clock.DiffTime](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.5.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html).  To parse and format use the functions in [Data.Time.Format](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.5.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Format.html).

Example:

```
import Data.Time
xyz :: String -> Maybe DiffTime
xyz x = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%H:%M:%S" x
```

Comment: Tom, could you give a quick example? I can't connect the dots.

Comment: I have to apologize because for some reason it seems that `DiffTime` cannot be parsed or formatted.  I opened a bug: https://github.com/haskell/time/issues/22

Comment: Interesting, let's see what happens. I'll work around it for now.